# Hierarchical JSON from csv python

Tags: python, json, csv, hierarchy

I have a dataset that is structured in a csv like this:

```
Name,code,count
Adam,01,48
Bill,01,32
Chris,01,4
Carl,01.01,5
Dave,01.01,1
David,01.01,1
Eric,01.01.01,26
Earl,01.01.01.01,2
Frank,01.01.01.01,2
Greg,01.01.01.02,2
Harold,01.01.01.03,7
Ian,01.01.01.03,3
Jack,01.01.01.03,1
John,01.01.01.04,10
Kyle,01.01.01.04,2
Larry,01.01.03.01,3
Mike,01.01.03.01.01,45
Nick,01.01.03.01.01.01,1
Oliver,01.01.03.01.01.02,16
Paul,01.01.03.01.01.03,23
```

I want to make a dictionary in python where the "name" and the "count" are key:value pairs (which is easy enough), but I want to organize a hierarchy based on the "code" number. i.e 01.01 is a child of 01 and I am not sure how to iterate over the data to make this happen. I eventually want to do a json dump of the whole structure, but it is how to structure the hierarchy that is getting me down. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output? You have three `01` elements at the beginning - how the `01.01` element should fit into the hierarchy? To which element to assign it?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of what the "hierarchy" looks like.

Comment: What are the up to 5 other fields that appear on some rows of the csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple and elegant way to implement a tree structure in Python uses a recursive [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
import csv, json
from collections import defaultdict

def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)

d = tree()

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for name, code, count in list(reader)[1:]:
        path = code.split('.')
        iter_node = d
        for node in path:
            iter_node = iter_node[node]
        iter_node['values'][name] = count

print json.dumps(d, indent=2)

{
  "01": {
    "values": {
      "Chris": "4", 
      "Bill": "32", 
      "Adam": "48"
    },
    "01": {
      "values": {
        "Dave": "1", 
        "Carl": "5", 
        "David": "1"
      },
      "03": {
        "01": {
          "01": {
            "02": {
              "values": {
                "Oliver": "16"
              }
            }, 
            "03": {
              "values": {
                "Paul": "23"
              }
            }, 
            "01": {
              "values": {
                "Nick": "1"
              }
            }, 
            "values": {
              "Mike": "45"
            }
          }, 
          "values": {
            "Larry": "3"
          }
        }
      }, 
      "01": { 
        "values": {
          "Eric": "26"
        }, 
        "02": {
          "values": {
            "Greg": "2"
          }
        }, 
        "03": {
          "values": {
            "Harold": "7", 
            "Ian": "3", 
            "Jack": "1"
          }
        }, 
        "01": {
          "values": {
            "Earl": "2", 
            "Frank": "2"
          }
        },
        "04": {
          "values": {
            "John": "10", 
            "Kyle": "2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet finds all the node of a tree without actually creating one. Tree and linked list implementation in Python is inefficient (*Beazley*).

```
from itertools import groupby
import csv

with open('csvfile.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

groups = groupby(reader, key=lambda row: row['code'])
nodes = {code: {item['Name']: item['count'] for item in group} for code,group in groups}

{'01': {'Adam': '48', 'Bill': '32', 'Chris': '4'},
 '01.01': {'Carl': '5', 'Dave': '1', 'David': '1'},
 '01.01.01': {'Eric': '26'},
 '01.01.01.01': {'Earl': '2', 'Frank': '2'},
 '01.01.01.02': {'Greg': '2'},
 '01.01.01.03': {'Harold': '7', 'Ian': '3', 'Jack': '1'},
 '01.01.01.04': {'John': '10', 'Kyle': '2'},
 '01.01.03.01': {'Larry': '3'},
 '01.01.03.01.01': {'Mike': '45'},
 '01.01.03.01.01.01': {'Nick': '1'},
 '01.01.03.01.01.02': {'Oliver': '16'},
 '01.01.03.01.01.03': {'Paul': '23'}}
```

Comment: Thanks C Panda! This worked great. Can you edit your response to put these lines in:  import csv

f = open("somefile.csv","r") .....i think some people will need them

Comment: @miltonjbradley which lines bdw?

Comment: I like the clean code. However, it does not make the tree structure explicit.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I am aware of that. As I don't know how the heirarchy looks like. I can't give any semantics to the result dict keys. My python tree will always be a `dict`. But i want to know how it looks like.

Comment: @CPanda I think it will be cleaner if you remove the redundant `code` from the inner `dicts`, and just use `name:count` key-value pairs. That would make the result it much less verbose without losing information.

Comment: @schwobaseggl That's not redundant "code". That's unwanted "output" which tallies the original input before making `name: count` transformation.

Comment: @CPanda Hmm.. maybe a misunderstanding of `code` ;) I meant the `'code'` keys in your output that were redundant. `d = {i: {x['Name']: x['count'] for x in g} for i, g in gs}` would produce what I spoke of.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Understood. My mistake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112064/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-c-panda).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do some standard tree structure, where you can access a tree structure, with missing node automatically created when accessing with a path.

Something like this.

```
class Node:
    def __init__( self, parent=None ):
        self.parent = parent
        self.store = {}
        self.children = {}

    def create_child( self, child_name ):
        self.children[ child_name ] = Node( self )

    #ancestry_line is a list of names
    def recursive_get_child( self, ancestry_line_names ):
        if len(ancestry_line_names) == 0:
            return self
        else:
            next_ancestor = ancestry_line_names[0]
            other_ancestors = ancestry_line_names[1:]
            if next_ancestor not in self.children:
                self.create_child( next_ancestor )
            return self.children[ next_ancestor ].recursive_get_child( other_ancestors )
```

The all you need to do is create a root node, and access the correct node from it thanks to the path.

```
root = Node()
for name, code, count in some_data_iterator():
    ancestry_line = code.split(".")
    root.get( ancestry_line ).store[ name ] = count
```

You can then create a method in `Node` to convert the Node structure into a pure dictionary structure usable to be dumped in `json`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This worked for a small list. As soon as I used the whole file I got a "too big to unpack" error